# typescript external callback binding within classes

Tags: javascript, typescript, callback, binding

I'm trying to bind properties of a class to a callback inside that class.

Quick example:

```
// caller
const first = (): void => {
  const testClass = new TestClass();
  testClass.second(() => {
    console.log(this.member) // error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'
  }
}

// TestClass
...
member: string = 'test';

second(cb: () => void) {
 const self = this;
 cb.bind(self)();
}
```

`this` seems to be possibly undefined.

How can I access the classes members from an outside callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Arrow Functions` are for automatic binding to the current scope and parent objects, so you can't call them with bindings of your callbacks.
so here javascript `interpreter` is trying to find the parent which the callback has been defined before.

```
// caller
const first = (): void => {
  const testClass = new TestClass();
  testClass.second(function() {
    console.log(this.member)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition before the console log to avoid print undefined objects.

from your example:

```
// caller
const first = (): void => {
  const testClass = new TestClass();
  testClass.second(() => {
    if (this.member) console.log(this.member)
  }
}

// TestClass
...
member: string = 'test';

second(cb: () => void) {
   const self = this;
    cb.bind(self)();
}
```